# Few problems with BRDF using Beckmann and GGX/Trowbridge-Reitz distribution for comparison

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I have been trying to wrap my head around physical based rendering these last 2.5 weeks and so far I managed to learn a lot, ask a lot of questions, and have some results, although I still have few problems that I would like to fix but the last few days I am stuck. I am want to continue working/learning more but now I don't know what else to do or how to proceed further, thus I need some guidance :(

One of the first problems that I can not figure out what is happening is when I get close to a shape. There is a cut-off problem with BRDF function that I have implemented. The second and third row are BRDF functions using Spherical Gaussian for Fresnel, and Schlick approximation. The second row Beckmann distribution NDF and the third one uses GGX/Trowbridge-Reitz as NDF.

I started implementing this referring to "Real Shading in Unreal Engine 4" and few other posts found while Google-ing.

What I believe the remaining things to do are:

- How to blend diffuse, reflection, and speculal better
- Fix the problem with the BRDF cut-off problem
- Evaluate if my shaders are producing good results based on the equation (it is the first time for me going this way and some comments would be very helpful as a guide on how to proceed in tweaking things)
- Fix specular factor in Phong (first row) shader, now I use material roughness as a blend factor when I mix Phong, skybox reflection and diffuse

The code I use for BRDF's is

```
    // geometry term Cook Torrance
float G(float NdotH, float NdotV, float VdotH, float NdotL) {

    float NH2 = 2.0 * NdotH;
    float g1 = (NH2 * NdotV) / VdotH;
    float g2 = (NH2 * NdotL) / VdotH;
    return min(1.0, min(g1, g2));
}

// Fresnel reflection term, Schlick approximation
float R_Fresnel(float VdotH) {
    return F0 + (1.0 - F0) * pow(2, (-5.55473 * (VdotH)-6.98316) * (VdotH));
}

// Normal distribution function, GGX/Trowbridge-Reitz
float D_GGX(float NdotH, float roughtness2) {

    float a = roughtness2 * roughtness2;
    float a2 = a*a;
    float t = ((NdotH * NdotH) * (a2 - 1.0) + 1.0);
    return a2 / (PI * t * t);

}

// Normal distribution function, Beckmann distribution 
float D_Beckmann(float NdotH, float mSquared) {

    float r1 = 1.0 / (4.0 * mSquared * pow(NdotH, 4.0));
    float r2 = (NdotH * NdotH - 1.0) / (mSquared * NdotH * NdotH);
    return (r1 * exp(r2));
}

// COOK TORRANCE BRDF
vec4 cookTorrance(Light light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal) {

    // do the lighting calculation for each fragment.
    float NdotL = max(dot(normal, direction), 0.0);

    float specular = 0.0;
    if (NdotL > 0.0)
    {
        vec3 eyeDir = normalize(cameraPosition);
        
        // calculate intermediary values
        vec3 halfVector = normalize(direction + eyeDir);
        float NdotH = max(dot(normal, halfVector), 0.0);
        float NdotV = max(dot(normal, eyeDir), 0.0); 
        float VdotH = max(dot(eyeDir, halfVector), 0.0);

        float matShininess = (material.shininess / 1000.0);
        float mSquared = (0.99 - matShininess) * (0.99 - matShininess);
        
        float geoAtt = G(NdotH, NdotV, VdotH, NdotL);
        
        float roughness = D_Beckmann(NdotH,  mSquared);
        float fresnel = R_Fresnel(VdotH);
        
        specular = (fresnel * geoAtt * roughness) / (NdotV * NdotL * PI);
    }

    vec3 finalValue = light.color * NdotL * (k + specular * (1.0 - k));
    
    return vec4(finalValue, 1.0);
}


vec4 cookTorrance_GGX(Light light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal) {

    // do the lighting calculation for each fragment.
    float NdotL = max(dot(normal, direction), 0.0);

    float specular = 0.0;
    if (NdotL > 0.0)
    {
        vec3 eyeDir = normalize(cameraPosition);

        // calculate intermediary values
        vec3 halfVector = normalize(direction + eyeDir);
        float NdotH = max(dot(normal, halfVector), 0.0);
        float NdotV = max(dot(normal, eyeDir), 0.0); 
        float VdotH = max(dot(eyeDir, halfVector), 0.0);

        float matShininess = (material.shininess / 1000.0);
        float mSquared = (0.99 - matShininess) * (0.99 - matShininess);

        float geoAtt = G(NdotH, NdotV, VdotH, NdotL);

        // NDF CHANGED TO GGX
        float roughness = D_GGX(NdotH, mSquared);
        float fresnel = R_Fresnel(VdotH);

        specular = (fresnel * geoAtt * roughness) / (NdotV * NdotL * PI);
    }

    vec3 finalValue = light.color * NdotL * (k + specular * (1.0 - k));

    return vec4(finalValue, 1.0);
}


void main() {
    //vec4 tempColor = vec4(material.diffuse, 1.0);
    vec4 tempColor = vec4(0.1);

    // interpolating normals will change the length of the normal, so renormalize the normal.
    vec3 normal = normalize(Normal);

    vec3 I = normalize(Position - cameraPosition);
    vec3 R = reflect(I, normalize(Normal));
    vec4 reflection = texture(skybox, R);

    // fix blending 
    float shininess = (material.shininess / 1000.0);
    vec4 tempFinalDiffuse = mix(tempColor, reflection, shininess);
    
    vec4 finalValue = cookTorrance_GGX(directionalLight.light, directionalLight.position, normal) + tempFinalDiffuse;
    // OR FOR COOK TORRANCE IN THE OTHER SHADER PROGRAM
    //vec4 finalValue = cookTorrance(directionalLight.light, directionalLight.position, normal) + tempFinalDiffuse;
    gl_FragColor = finalValue;
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0); // TESTING AND DEBUGGING FRAG OUT
}
```

The results i have so far are lik in pictures below
[image]
[image]

EDIT :: I managed to solve few problems and implement environment sampling given in "Real Shading in Unreal Engine 4" but still I just cant figure out why I have that cut-off problem and I have a problem with reflection now after sampling. :(

Also I moved Phong that i tough in books and online tutorial to BDRF Blinn-Phong for better comparison.

My shader now looks like this.

```
vec4 brdf_GGX(Light light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal) {

float specular = 0.0;

float matShininess = 1.0 - (material.shininess / 1000.0);

vec2 randomPoint;
vec4 finalColor = vec4(0.0);
vec4 totalLambert = vec4(0.0);

const uint numberSamples = 32;
for (uint sampleIndex = 0; sampleIndex < numberSamples; sampleIndex++)
{
    randomPoint = hammersley2d(sampleIndex, numberSamples);

    vec3 H = ImportanceSampleGGX(randomPoint, matShininess, normal);
    vec3 L = 2.0 * dot(normal, H) * H - normal;

    vec3 R = reflect(L, normalize(normal));
    totalLambert += texture(skybox, -R);
}

totalLambert = totalLambert / numberSamples;

float NdotL = max(dot(normal, direction), 0.0);
if (NdotL > 0.0)
{
    vec3 eyeDir = normalize(cameraPosition);

    // calculate intermediary values
    vec3 halfVector = normalize(direction + eyeDir);
    float NdotH = max(dot(normal, halfVector), 0.0);
    float NdotV = max(dot(normal, eyeDir), 0.0);
    float VdotH = max(dot(eyeDir, halfVector), 0.0);

    float mSquared = clamp(matShininess * matShininess, 0.01, 0.99);
    
    float geoAtt = G(NdotH, NdotV, VdotH, NdotL);

    float roughness = D_Beckmann(NdotH, mSquared);
    float fresnel = R_Fresnel(VdotH);

    specular = (fresnel * geoAtt * roughness) / (NdotV * NdotL * PI);
}   
        vec3 finalValue = light.color * NdotL * (k + specular * (1.0 - k));
        
        return vec4(finalValue, 1.0) * totalLambert;
}
```

Current results look like this (NOTE: I used skybox sampling only in the third GGX model, do the same for other shaders tomorrow)

[image]

EDIT:: OK i am figuring out what is happening but still i can not fix it. I have problems when sampling. I have no idea how to translate normalized ray to proper cube map reflection after sampling. If you can notice in pictures I lost the correct reflection that sphere does to environment map. I just have a simple/flat texture on each sphere and now I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: not a real answer. but I think there is some amount of hard cutoff that is native to Cook Torrance. Second problem is that your `R` is a reflection of reflection. Do it manually, OR with `reflect` intrinsic. but you don't need to compute `L` this way. you need to reflect `V` off the normal, that's all.

Comment: I would double check my normals and avoid floating point comparisons.